# Efficiently recompute bounding rectangle of point set when one point moved

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I have an array of points. I need to find minimal bounding rectangle which contains all points every time when points are moved.

It can be done iterating over all points and finding min/max coordinates every time when one point is moved - `O(n)` on every move.

I'm wondering, can be this done faster than `O(n)` on every move after first?

I thought I can find initial bounding rectangle and then somehow only update it.

Comment: Axis aligned rectangle, or no?

Comment: Yes, aligned to horizontal X and vertical Y axes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to use 4 heaps,

1. Minheap for x coordinates
2. Maxheap for x coordinates
3. Minheap for y coordinates
4. Maxheap for y coordinates

The top entries of the heaps give the bounding box location, and the heaps can be updated in O(logn) time for each moved point.

(Note this only gives an axis aligned bounding box)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking what data structure I need - array, linked list and sorted linked list give also `O(n)`. I don't know much about heaps, but I will learn about.

Comment: Hmm...  When a point is moved, how is it identified?  Unless we somehow already know where it lives in each heap, we need to *find* it first, which is O(n) (at least for binary heaps).  Using 2 binary trees instead of 4 heaps would allow O(log n) lookup time for the moves as well as for finding the BB.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You can store a pointer in the heap to the point structure, and a pointer in the point structure to the location in the heap.  Whenever you move an element in the heap you also update the corresponding pointer in the point structure.  However, binary trees may well be an even better choice.

Comment: Fair enough.  Though it occurs to me that if the point queries arrive in the form "Move (x, y) to (a, b)" (instead of "by handle" -- as in "Move the point represented by the `struct` at address z to (a, b)") then the (x, y) is probably being converted to the address z that your approach needs by looking it up in... a binary tree :)  (Or a hash, admittedly.)